# A question about Widely Connected subsets of Euclidean spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let E be a finite dimensional Euclidean space whose dimension is at least two. Can there exist a subset of E that is both dense in E and Widely Connected?

Comment: Define "widely connected"?

Comment: Is it: A nondegenerate connected space $X$ is widely connected if each nondegenerate connected subset of $X$ is dense in $X$?

Comment: Yes, that is the definition